# What is the best way to get with of an element with horizontal scrollbars using angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a div with fixed width. So if content goes over the available width, a horizontal scrollbar appears. Now I want to add a button which should increase the width of the div such that it does not require any horizontal scrollbar. Meaning, it should set whatever is the required width to accommodate the entire content in it.

I tried getting the width using innerWidth which returns incorrect width. Quick google search mentioned about scrollWidth, offsetWidth but there are no such methods in angular.js

Comment: Please post the things that you have done till now

Comment: Hi Nitheesh, this is the first step of the task. I tried getting the width using innerWidth which returns incorrect width. Quick google search mentioned about scrollWidth, offsetWidth but there are no such methods in angularjs.